# Why does my UILabel.text fail to update?

Tags: xcode, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

Hello to all and thank you in advance.  I am trying to change the text property of a UILabel on a ViewController via code when the view ***reutrns to the foreground***.  I am using "applicationDidBecomeActive" in the AppDelegate.m file to call a method on the ViewController.m, this works.  The problem is that neither the method I call or the "ViewDidLoad" method will update the UIlabel.text after a settings change in the settings app.  The text remains unchanged almost as if it is sending the string from the last update.  I am fetching a NSUserDefault value from the settings bundle each time to include in the text string.  The fetch returns OK.  The UILabel just wont update.  Just FYI I am calling synchronize before the self view which triggers the "viewDidLoad".

Just to clarify, when the "viewDidLoad" method runs the first time on launch, it works fine.  It is only after hitting the home button, changing a setting in the settings app and then returning to my app that the UILabel lblResultTitle.text now will not update.
Please Please help...

Here is the code in the ViewDidLoad:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
  NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
  self.lblResultTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Speed %@ =", [settings stringForKey:kunit]] ;

  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `self.lblResultTitle` is nil or not connected to anything.  Check that first.  Also, if you want to update the label often (i.e. more than just at the first load time), don't put that label updating code in `viewDidLoad`!  Put it somewhere else (in a new function) and have `viewDidLoad` call that new function.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Michael.  I can successfully update it from any method after the view is up on the screen.  So I believe the connection is good.  Xcode shows a filled circle on the IBOutlet.  I will try to call a method from "ViewDidLoad" next.

Comment: OK i added a new method that is called from "viewDidLoad" and moved the code down to that new method.  Same result, it works the first time, but not on subsequent...

Comment: check to see if "`self.lblResultTitle`" is nil in those subsequent calls.

Comment: I just added NSLog(@" %@", self.lblResultTitle.text); to the new method just before the other code,  It retuned (null)... Why is this if the view is clearly up and loaded?

Comment: how do you instantiate `lblResultTitle`?  Is it an "`IBOutlet`" in a xib file or did you create it programatically?  You may want to edit your question to show more code (like where "`lblResultTitle`" is actually set).

Comment: I sure seems to me now like a timing issue.  Perhaps the connections are not re-established quickly enough to catch the update?

Comment: lblResultTitle is instantiated in ViewController.h and connected as an IBoutlet.  I am using storyboarding.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:  Calling a method to update from AppWillEnterForeground or APPxBecomeActive will not work because the app's storyboard is not executing yet.  For this case the app must listen for messages sent from NSUserDefaults.  After implementing the necessary code for this I have the solution I needed.  The problem was not actually the UILabel.  It was much deeper than that.  It's all good now!  Thank you!